# Is it possible to override WebRTC connection timeout?

Tags: android, webrtc, multipeer-connectivity, peer

I have implemented WebRTC calls in my project, When the internet got disconnected then WebRTC throws a disconnected state immediately and Closed/Failed state after 10/15 secs.
Can I override these 10/15 secs timeout to 30secs?

Is it possible?